# How to unselect a listbox datatemplate item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

```
<TabItem Name="tbInActive" Header="Previous" Width="100" Height="100">
    <ListBox Name="lbActive" 
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SelectedItemContainer}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  >
                <EventDet:EventSumDetail x:Name="ItemCtrl"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=lbInActive, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <!-- ... -->
</TabItem>
```

In my codebehind I tried

`this.lbActive.SelectedItem = null;` and  `this.lbActive.UnselectAll();` and    (edit) `this.lbActive.SelectedIndex = -1;`

But they had no effect.

Comment: have you tried setting the selected index to -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why `this.lbActive.SelectedItem = null;` should not work. (It works on a clean slate ListBox)

I'm quite sure the problem lies with your custom parts, either `SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=lbInActive, Path=SelectedItem}"` is forcing a selection, or a binding in your `ItemContainerStyle` does so.

Answer (score 0):

I guest that EventDet:EventSumDetail is a kind of ListBoxItem or something like that.
The problem you had a OneWay binding(by default)... you had to explicitly make it TwoWay binding.. like this:

```
<EventDet:EventSumDetail SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=lbInActive, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Also, you don't need to name (x:Name="ItemCtrl"), in this case it's unnecessary.